# wpf richtext box image moving and flowdocument content as email

Tags: wpf, image, richtextbox, flowdocument

I have 3 questions:

1. Is there any way to move the image in the wpf richtextbox using mouse ?

   I am adding the image to the rtb is as follows:

   ```
   BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\daf\apple.png"));
   Image image = new Image();            
   image.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
   image.Source = bitmap;
   image.Width = 60;
   image.Height = 70;
   myRTB.BeginChange();
   TextPointer tp = myRTB.CaretPosition.GetPositionAtOffset(0, LogicalDirection.Forward);
   InlineUIContainer imageContainer = new InlineUIContainer(image, tp);
   myRTB.CaretPosition = imageContainer.ElementEnd;
   myRTB.EndChange();
   myRTB.Focus();
   ```
2. After putting image in the rtb and writing some words on it, i saved it to html format and i got the html code from richtextbox flowdocument content. But when i am reusing the same saved html code back to (html to xaml converter) flow document, the image size is very big.

   In the html code:

   ```
   "IMG src=\"file:///C:\daf\apple.png\" STYLE=\"width:60;height:70;font-family:tahoma;font-size:11;\"
   ```

   This is same html code part when i saved the RTB content to html. But when rendering back using this saved html, the image is very big.

   For testing purpose, i changed the width and height value to 30 in the html code and tried. but still the image is displayed as very large.

   Any idea about it ?
3. Is there anyway to send the content of wpf richtextbox flowdocument (with images in it) as email ?

Many many thanks for it.